How to convert COBOL statement into dynamic Json Structure using Python
#Example COBOL statement 
cobol_statement = "MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01(1) FOR FIELD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3))"

I need a json structure to covert this COBOL i need a result as
{"cursor": "NBS-DS-01(1)", "for": ["NBS-DS-01","NBS-DS-02(2)","NBS-DS-03(3)"]}

I need the json structure to be dynamic whatever the field I'am adding to be convert automatically

You can use regular expressions

You can try this regular expression. If you use a different format you need to reconstruct the regex.
import re
import json

def cobol_to_json(statement):
    pattern = r"MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT ([\w-]+\(\d+\)) FOR FIELD \(([\w-]+(?:\(\d+\))?(?:, [\w-]+(?:\(\d+\))?)*)\)"
    match = re.match(pattern, statement)
    if match:
        cursor = match.group(1)
        fields_str = match.group(2)
        fields = [field.strip() for field in fields_str.split(',')]
        result = {
            "cursor": cursor,
            "for": fields
        }
        return json.dumps(result, indent=4)
    else:
        return "invalid statement"


statement = "MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01(1) FOR FIELD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3))"
result = cobol_to_json(statement)
print(result)

Output:
{
    "cursor": "NBS-DS-01(1)",
    "for": [
        "NBS-DS-01",
        "NBS-DS-02(2)",
        "NBS-DS-03(3)"
    ]
}


i had this regex pattern = r"(MOD(?:IFY)?\sMAP|MOD\sMAP)\s(?:TEMP\s)?(?:CURSOR(?:\sAT)?|FIELD|FOR|DFLD)(?:\s(?:AT|FIELD|DFLD))?\s(?:((?:\w+(?:-\w+)(?:(\d+))?)(?:,\s\w+(?:-\w+)(?:(\d+))?)))(?:\s(?:ATTR(?:IBUTES)?|FOR\sFIELD|OF|FOR))?\s(?:((?:\w+(?:-\w+)(?:(\d+))?)(?:,\s\w+(?:-\w+)(?:(\d+))?)))(?:\s(?:ATTRIBUTES?|ATTR|ATTRIBUTE)\s([\w\s]+))?"

i need to convert the below cobal statement MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01 FOR DFLD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3))
MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01(1) FOR FIELD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3))
MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01
MODIFY MAP CURSOR FOR DFLD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3))
MODIFY MAP FOR DFLD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3))
MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01(1) FOR DFLD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3)) ATTR MDT
MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01(1) FOR DFLD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3)) ATTRIBUTES MDT

you need to reconstruct a new regex for the new statement. you can take help from chatgpt about constructing the regex every time you need, maybe it can generate for you

Try something like this:
import re
import json

def cobol_to_json(cobol_statement):
    cursor_pattern = r'CURSOR\s+AT\s+([\w-]+\(\d+\))'
    for_pattern = r'FOR\s+FIELD\s+\((.*?)\)'
    cursor_match = re.search(cursor_pattern, cobol_statement, re.IGNORECASE)
    for_match = re.search(for_pattern, cobol_statement, re.IGNORECASE)
    if cursor_match and for_match:
        cursor = cursor_match.group(1)
        fields = [field.strip() for field in for_match.group(1).split(',')]
        result = {"cursor": cursor, "for": fields}
        return json.dumps(result, indent=4)
    else:
        return None


cobol_statement = "MODIFY MAP CURSOR AT NBS-DS-01(1) FOR FIELD (NBS-DS-01, NBS-DS-02(2), NBS-DS-03(3))"
json_result = cobol_to_json(cobol_statement)
if json_result:
    print(json_result)
else:
    print("Failed to parse COBOL statement.")

Output:
{
    "cursor": "NBS-DS-01(1)",
    "for": [
        "NBS-DS-01",
        "NBS-DS-02(2"
    ]
}


thanks for your concern but i need a result as follows                                                                 {
cursor": "NBS-DS-01(1)",
"for": [
"NBS-DS-01","NBS-DS-02(2)","NBS-DS-03(3)"
]                                                                                                     }
